# How to split a DataFrame into multiple DataFrames based off part of a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

For a project, I'm scraping some tabled scheduling data for my university using BeautifulSoup then reading it into a DataFrame with pandas.read_html(). However, the data is in one large table that is visually split into multiple tables using two headings: a college heading (i.e., 'College of Engineering') and then headings for each column (i.e., 'Course', 'Start').

ex:

---

COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING

---

Course | Start | End | ...

---

Pandas correctly parses the headings into a MultiIndex where the first part of each index tuple is the college, and the second part is the column heading. However, I want multiple DataFrames with single column indicies, separated by college. How would I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, its a multi level index of college name followed by columns and you want to split by college name.

```
Assuming df is your multiindex column dataframe,
di = {}
for i in df.columns.levels[0]:
    di[i] = df[i]
```

This will create a dictionary with key value pairs of colleges and corresponding dataframes